# How to fix unexpected output in recursive C program?

Tags: c, math, recursion

I am attempting to write a simple recursive function to evaluate Associated Legendre Polynomials in C.  As of now, I only have it written up to L=4 and M=3.  I am using the seventh recurrence formula from the following Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long double Legendre(int L, int M, double x){

    if((M == 0) && (L == 0)){
        return 1;
    }

    if((M == 0) && (L == 1)){
        return x;
    }

    if((M == 0) && (L == 2)){
        return (1/2) * ((3*x*x) - 1);
    }

    if((M == 0) && (L == 3)){
        return (1/2) * ((5*pow(x,3)) - (3*x));
        }

   if((M == 0) && (L == 4)){
            return (1/8) * (3 - (30*x*x) + (35*pow(x,4)));
        }

else if(M > 0){

        return (((L - M + 1)*x*Legendre(L,M-1,x))
                - ((L + M - 1)*Legendre(L-1,M-1,x)))
                / sqrt(1-(x*x));

    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void){

    int L = 4;
    int M = 2;
    double x = 0.6;

    printf("%Lf\n",Legendre(L,M,x));
}
```

As per Mathematica, the Associated Legendre Polynomial with L=4, M=2, and x=0.6 should be 7.3.  However, when I run the above program, I get the following result:

```
$ gcc Rodrigues.c -o Rodrigues
$ ./Rodrigues
0.000000
$
```

(My source file name is Rodrigues.c).  The output should be around 7.3, not 0.  The code also produces other non-zero (though still incorrect) values for different Ls and Ms.  I am suspecting it is because I have somehow messed up the recursion (as you can tell, I am relatively new to programming). What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: (1/2) is equal to 0 as it's an int operation

Comment: I agree with @marcadian about the primary problem — you're multiplying by zero because of integer division, so you get a zero result.  (When I add decimal points after the 1's in `(1/2)` etc, I get `7.296000` as the answer.)  You're using a `long double` return value, which is a little odd since the only calculation that is done using `long double` is the `else if (M > 0)` calculation.  All the others are done in `double` at best (though the result is then converted to `long double` before it is returned).

Comment: You're missing the difference between integer and float division in C. Any math that appears to be totally integer, will be computed as totally integer. For instance, `1/2` is two integers. So that's zero. Likewise, `1/8`. The simplest answer for you is to append `.0` to at least one of your numbers in those expressions. (You can do `1.` without the zero, but if you're new, you probably want the reminder.)